# How to create Dto using Json object C# with multiple data types array

Tags: c#, json, dto

Need to create Dto class supporting multiple data types in an array JSON object, due to it has Integer, string values in the array, have declared dynamic object declaration but getting an error, do I need to create a custom JsonConvert class to process Json array multiple data type array data?

```
{
  "apiVersion": 1,
  "data": {
          "unnamedFields": [
            1,
            "T",
             1,
          
            350000,
       "\\u0000",
            "\\u0000",         
         ]
  }
}


 Have created  property 
        
  /// <summary>
        /// Un Named Fields
        /// </summary>
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "unnamedFields")]
        public List<UnNamedField>[] UnNamedFields { get; set; }
     

    public class UnNamedField
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  UnName Feild
        /// </summary>        
        public **dynamic** UnnamedFields{ get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the following objects

```
class Dto
{
    public int ApiVersion { get; set; }
    public DtoData Data { get; set; }
}

class DtoData
{
    public dynamic[] UnnamedFields { get; set; }
}
```

and then use it like this

```
[HttpGet("test")]
public IActionResult GetDynamicJsonArray()
{
    return Ok(new Dto
    {
        ApiVersion = 1,
        Data = new DtoData
        {
            UnnamedFields = new dynamic[] { 1, "T", 1, 35000, "\\u0000" }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Honey.. Thanks for the reply, I would like to process without hard-coding those UnnamedFields,

Comment: @MohanK Could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Thank you it helped me: public dynamic[] UnnamedFields { get; set; }